# Writing large (~89,000 elements) array to range

Tags: excel, vba

After populating my arrays based on some criteria I am attempting to write two temporary arrays to two different ranges on the worksheet. Using my current method with the transposed arrays I begin to get `#N/A` values after row 24,392. I'm not sure how to get past the size limitations of `Application.Transpose`.

`LastRowA` and `LastRowB` are declared globally as `long`. The value of `LastRowA` is >11,000 and `LastRowB` is >80,000

```
Sub Test()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'call subs to find last rows for each sheet
LastRowASub
LastRowBSub

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim x As Double
Dim y As Double

Dim Arr1() As Variant
Dim Arr2() As Variant
Dim Temp1() As String
Dim Temp2() As String
ReDim Arr1(1 To LastRowA - 1, 3)
ReDim Arr2(1 To LastRowB - 1)
ReDim Temp1(1 To LastRowB - 1)
ReDim Temp2(1 To LastRowB - 1)

'populate first array
For x = 1 To LastRowA - 1
    Arr1(x, 1) = sheet1.Range("k" & x + 1)
    Arr1(x, 2) = sheet1.Range("c" & x + 1)
    Arr1(x, 3) = sheet1.Range("a" & x + 1)
Next x

'populate second array
For y = 1 To LastRowB - 1
    Arr2(y, 1) = sheet2.Range("f" & y + 1)
Next y

'populate two temporary arrays based on matching between arrays 1 and 2
For i = 1 To UBound(Arr2)
    For j = 1 To UBound(Arr1)
        If Arr1(j, 1) = Arr2(i, 1) And Not IsEmpty(Arr1(j, 2)) Then
            Temp1(i) = Arr1(j, 2)
            Temp2(i) = Arr1(j, 3)
        End If
    Next j
Next i

'write temp arrays to sheet2
sheet2.Range("C2:C" & ExtLRow) = Application.Transpose(Temp1)
sheet2.Range("G2:G" & ExtLRow) = Application.Transpose(Temp2)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Everything is working as expected other than the transposed arrays returning `#N/A`.

Comment: you should debug the values in your arrays `Temp1` and `Temp2` , from element 25,000 and after. I am using `Transpose` for arrays with 150K rows, and it's working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the arrays 2 dimensional with one column:

```
ReDim Temp1(1 To LastRowB - 1,1 to 1)
ReDim Temp1(1 To LastRowB - 1,1 to 1)
```

Then when you assign the values:

```
Temp1(i,1) = Arr1(j, 2)
Temp2(i,1) = Arr1(j, 3)
```

Then you do not need the `Application.Transpose`

```
sheet2.Range("C2:C" & ExtLRow) = Temp1
sheet2.Range("G2:G" & ExtLRow) = Temp2
```

---

Also to speed things up avoid the loops altogether:

```
Sub Test()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'call subs to find last rows for each sheet
LastRowASub
LastRowBSub

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim x As Double
Dim y As Double

Dim Arr1() As Variant
Dim Arr2() As Variant
Dim Temp1() As Variant
Dim Temp2() As Variant

ReDim Temp1(1 To LastRowB - 1, 1 To 1)
ReDim Temp2(1 To LastRowB - 1, 1 To 1)

'populate first array
Arr1 = Sheet1.Range("A2:K" & lastrowa).Value


'populate second array
Arr2 = sheet2.Range("F2:F" & LastRowB).Value

'populate two temporary arrays based on matching between arrays 1 and 2
For i = 1 To UBound(Arr2, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(Arr1, 1)
        If Arr1(j, 11) = Arr2(i, 1) And Not IsEmpty(Arr1(j, 3)) Then
            Temp1(i, 1) = Arr1(j, 3)
            Temp2(i, 1) = Arr1(j, 1)
        End If
    Next j
Next i

'write temp arrays to sheet2
sheet2.Range("C2:C" & ExtLRow).Value = Temp1
sheet2.Range("G2:G" & ExtLRow).Value = Temp2

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```